# C++ , Вводятся числа до тех пор, пока не будет введён 0, найти самое большое отрицательное число

Tags: c++

не понимаю, что не так
Вводимые числа могут быть как отрицательные так и положительные
вводные данные : 5 3 4 -2 -3 0 вывод: -2
вводные данные : -2 -3 2 5 7 0 вывод: -2

```
double num, max;
 cin >> num;
 max = num;
 while (num != 0) {
     if (max < num || (max >= 0 && num < 0)) {
         max = num;
        
     }
     cin >> num;
 }
     if (max >= 0) { cout << "ne to tz"<<" "<<max; }
     else cout << max;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "самое большое отрицательное"? Из -10, -5, -2 это -2 или -10? ведь -2 > -10...

Comment: да, верно, должно выводится -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double max = 0;
max = 0;
for(double num; cin >> num && num != 0;)
{
    if (num > 0) continue;
    if (max < num || max == 0) max = num;
}

if (max >= 0) { cout << "ne to tz"<<" "<<max; }
else cout << max;
```

Comment: Cпасибо! Была такая же мысль, не знал как оформить в плане синтаксиса, новичок...